# How to fire mailto urls from action method

Tags: javascript, mailto, window.location, actionmethod

I am a beginner in MVC. I want to develop an action method in MVC which fires `Mailto:?body=body goes here.&subject=test subject` and so the default mail client will automatically populate the email for the user. Right now I have `List<String>` which contain `mailto:` urls.

Please, if you have any experience or demo code it will be helpful to me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does action method mean? Is this in a particular framework or just raw JavaScript?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC applications is organized around controllers and action methods. The controller defines action methods. Controllers can include as many action methods as needed.
Action methods typically have a one-to-one mapping with user interactions. Examples of user interactions include entering a URL into the browser, clicking a link, and submitting a form. Each of these user interactions causes a request to be sent to the server. In each case, the URL of the request includes information that the MVC framework uses to invoke an action method.

Comment: Consider adding the asp.net tag and/or mentioning this in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My ActionMethod**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult emailTemplate()
{
    List<String> str = new List<String>();
    str.Add("Mailto:?body=Hello1&subject=test subject1");
    str.Add("Mailto:?body=Hello2&subject=test subject2");
    return Json(str);
}
```

**JavaScript Function in view**

```
function SendMailClicked() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/emailTemplate",
            //data: "{'ReviewComponentIds':'1,2,3'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                jQuery.each(response, function () {

                    window.location.href = this + '\n';
                });
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert('failure');
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 9):

try this :

```
window.location.href = "mailto:address@dmail.com";
```

with body

```
window.location.href = "mailto:address@dmail.com?body=yourBody";
```

Event with jquery

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    window.location.href = "mailto:address@dmail.com?body=yourBody";
});
```

Comment: Thank you Bastien for your reply. I know this stuff. I want this is from action method. In my scenario I am processing some logic over server and genrate ``mailto:..`` links and these  links i need to fire from action method itself. @Bastien D

Comment: But how to call this from action method ``window.location.href = "mailto:address@dmail.com";``  ???
and mail list is multiple

Comment: if i want a whole div content instead of specific string then how can i do that?